# Best Agile Methodogy for a Small DevOps Team

Tags: agile

We have a smaller Dev team of around 20 developers working on 2 specific business towers. We also have a Sec and Ops team managing ticket based work. The idea is to combine Dev Sec and Ops. Wanted to ask what agile methodology suits this kind of transformation?

Comment: What kind of management tools are being used by your organization? And also what methodology does the development team uses now?

Comment: We are doing development work based on waterfall model and use Microsoft project and excel for tracking. We are planning for a complete transformation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would recommend to move to Scrum for your development team. For the Operations I would recommend Kanban. Once the team have reached a maturity level when they are comfortable with their respective way of working, go for ScrumBan when you transform your teams together moving towards DevOps. I would also recommend using JIRA.